# how to prevent DialogFragment from resize

Tags: java, android

i have a DialogFragment that calling another DialogFragment, 
im trying to pervent the sconde one from resize when the keyboard open.

the activity that calling the both fragments are not resize (in the menifast
it  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing")

i tried  on the DialogFragment the following:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

and

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

and it still resize when the keyboard opend.

any idea why ?

Comment: ok i found a solution:
if tou use 

 dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

to determined the layout size, than it is impossible to prevent DialogFragment from resize, youi need to use a "fix size" like:

(int) (getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight()*0.9)